# How to find the longest path that connects two leaves in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

how can I find the length of the longest path that connects two leaves through the root in a binary tree?

- The function must be recursive and it must return the length of the
  longest path.
- I only need the pseudo-code

[image: This image explain better: the longest path is from 7 to 13 through the root. In this case the length is 7]

I've just read that what I'm looking for is called **Diameter of the tree**

Comment: Do you mean "the only path" since it's a tree? Or since you want to go through the root, could your "path" backtrack onto itself?

Comment: he want to find two most distant leaves.

Comment: @MarekR understood well. It is simply the sum of the height of the left part of the tree + the height of the right part of the tree but I don't know how to write it recursively

Answer (score 0):

As a note, the diameter of a binary tree isn’t necessarily equal to the length of the longest path through the root. Consider a complete binary tree that’s been modified by having an extra node added up over the root - then the best path doesn’t pass through the root at all.

If you must pass through the root, then the longest path is the one that goes to the deepest nodes in the left and right subtrees. So think about writing a helper function that finds the deepest node in a subtree, and see if you can use this as a starting point.